# Exchange 2013 SP1 on WIndows 2012 R2 SMTP Issue

Tags: windows-server-2012, smtp, exchange-2013

I have  Exchange Server 2013 SP1 installed on Windows 2012 R2.  This is a clean install on a new stand alone server.

I have added 1 user account into Active Directory and have the receive connectors set to default settings plus anonymous access set.

I am trying to connect to the server using outlook 2013 and outlook 2016.

The user account connects to POP3 ok but whatever settings I have on the Exchange server the SMTP connection from outlook always refuses the login saying the following :-

Send test e-mail message: Your e-mail server rejected your login. Verify your user name and password for this account in Account Settings.

after several days of fighting with this im really hoping someone can point me in the right direction on this.

Thanks in advance

Additional Info :  When I connect using telnet and try to send I get 451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX3

Comment: Why are you using POP/SMTP in Outlook? Why don't you connect Outlook natively to Exchange?

Comment: most of the devices are laptops with multiple email addresses that can be connecting from anywhere over any network type.  Its just easier to manage the mailboxes and contents on the devices rather than end up with multiple exchange files on the clients.  Also Outlook is just where I am starting from.  As the outlook configuration worked to the previous server its not an outlook issue and as the problem appears to be server side i will need to fix it for other device/client types.

Comment: so the short answer is - personal prefference